# Is this the list of ordered pairs $(A,B)$, where $A, B$ are subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $A∪B=\{1,2,3\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

The list I came up with is:
$(\phi,\{1,2,3\}), (\{1\},\{2,3\}), (\{2\},\{1,3\}),(\{3\},\{1,2\})$ - for the ones with no intersection, 
and then $\{1,2,3\}$ paired each of $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},$ and $\{2,3\}$ - for the ones with an intersection.

Together, that's $10$, and then I doubled that because these are ordered pairs, so each of those could be listed with their order reversed.

So that's $20$ ordered pairs such that $A \cup B = \{1,2,3\}$.

I then tried to compute this using Inclusion-Exclusion, but only got this far-

The number of total ordered pairs from $\{1,2,3\}$ is $2^3\times 2^3 =64$. (I derived this from the answer given in the link I list below, thanks for that.)

Then I tried to compute complements. The number of sets that don't include 1 either contain $2$ or don't, and either contain $3$ or don't. So there's $2^2$ of those, and when paired with themselves, there are a total of $8$ ordered pairs not containing a $1$. Similarly, there are 8 ordered pairs not containing a $2$, and $8$ without a $3$.

So of the $64$ total pairs, $24$ can be discounted.

But that's as far as I got. I'm guessing even more can be discounted, but can't figure out how to approach that. Am I close?

(I did get some help from this question [Number of ordered pairs of subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885790/number-of-ordered-pairs-of-subsets) but this was also a more complex situation than this one, where A and B can be any subset of $\{1,2,3\}$, just so long as $A \cup B$ is $\{1,2,3\}$.)

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: How about $(\{1,2\},\{2,3\})$. Did you count that?

Comment: The $7$ pairs you missed are $(\{1,3\},\{2,3\})$, $(\{1,2\},\{2,3\})$, $(\{2,3\},\{1,3\})$, $(\{2,3\},\{1,2\})$, $(\{1,2\},\{1,3\})$, $(\{1,3\},\{1,2\})$, and $(\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3\})$. No wonder you missed a few, listing them haphazardly like that instead of systematically.

Comment: The total number of pairs is $3^3=27$. You have $3$ choices for each of the $3$ numbers $1,2,3$: put it only in $A$, put it only in $B$, or put it in both $A$ and $B$.